# How do I write a GROUP BY or HAVING clause in Diesel?

Tags: rust, group-by, having, rust-diesel

I'm trying to convert the following SQL query into corresponding Rust Diesel code:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM BookStore
WHERE BookName IN ('Lord of the Rings', 'Hobbit')
GROUP BY StoreId
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT BookName) = 2
```

I was able to translate it thus far into:

```rust
let bookNames = vec!["Lord of the Rings", "Hobbit"];

let subquery = bookStores::table
.select(count_star())
.filter(bookName.eq_any(bookNames));
```

which I believe translates to:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM BookStore
WHERE BookName IN ('Lord of the Rings', 'Hobbit')
```

I'm having trouble finding any Diesel equivalent for the `GROUP BY` and the `HAVING` SQL clauses. Do these clauses even exist in Diesel?

Comment: https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/issues/210

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems like a group by clause has been added but it doesn't seem like the having clause has been implemented yet. Is this still the case or did I miss some information in the post?

Comment: *It seems like a group by clause has been added* — it has [not](https://docs.rs/diesel/1.4.5/diesel/associations/trait.GroupedBy.html): "This function does not generate a GROUP BY SQL statement, as it operates on data structures already loaded from the database"

Comment: To just add a few words about the current state of things:

* On the 1.x release series there is [this](https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel/blob/1.4.x/diesel/src/query_dsl/group_by_dsl.rs) hidden by default (read as "not part of the supported public API") function which allows to specify group by clauses 

* 2.0 (the next release) will probably introduce at least some official support for group by clauses, therefore the linked issue mentions that something has been implemented

* Having clauses are not supported on any version yet

Comment: would you mind sharing `count_star()`?

Comment: did you fix this problem?@user1842633

Comment: use `sql_query` https://docs.diesel.rs/diesel/fn.sql_query.html